MariaDB slow log - sleeping state queries implementation
I'm using MariaDB 10.0.36, and I see a lot of open threads in sleep under the command column, so I guess that the application doesn't close the connection to the DB,
Eventually, the thread will close after reaching the time out of 300 seconds.
I want to know what queries are executed at the start of these threads.
I tried to run slowlog with this configuration:
log_slow_filter admin,filesort,filesort_on_disk,full_join,full_scan,query_cache,query_cache_miss,tmp_table,tmp_table_on_disk
log_slow_rate_limit 100
log_slow_verbosity  innodb,query_plan,explain
slow_launch_time    2
slow_query_log  OFF
slow_query_log_file slowlog240924.log
long_query_time     100.000000

Example from the slow log:
# User@Host: x @ x
# Thread_id: 9248835  Schema: x  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 0.000067  Lock_time: 0.000013  Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 1
#
# explain: id   select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
# explain: 1    SIMPLE  documents   const   PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   const   1   
#
SET timestamp=1727181672;
select * from documents where documents.id = 97863 limit 1;

When I walk over the slow log I see that all the queries that were logged are with Query_time: of less than a second.
My question is: those queries I see with short execution times are the ones I'm looking for just with their real execution time and it catches them because the thread ended after 300 seconds or something is wrong with my configuration?

long_query_time = 100.000000 seconds will give you only very long queries.  "1" is useful for finding naughty queries; "0".
Consider summarizing the slowlog via pt-query-digest or mysqlslow.  See SlowLog
The "general log" gives you all queries from all connections.  Caution: it can write lots to disk.
select * from documents where documents.id = 97863 limit 1; should take only millisecond(s), assuming PRIMARY KEY(id).

Thanks for the reply Rick.
But why do I see queries that run in less than 100 sec in my slow log?
Maybe the reason is the log_slow_filter?
For example, if a query runs in less than 100 seconds but uses filesort, will I see this query in the slow log?

@Agar123 - Probably some of the items in log_slow_filter apply.  I prefer to turn off all flags and set the time low.

See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#log_slow_filter

Thanks, from what im reading only the filter not_using_index is applied if it doesn't exceed the threshold.
But the query above used an index and was still logged; what could be the cause?

@Agar123 - I see several items in log_slow_filter,
